# updated my gradle properties but now this java error pops up

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load wrapper properties from

```
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:60)Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 62: 
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown So        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrl(WrapperExecutor.java:81)        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.prepareDistributionUri(WrapperExecutor.java:70)        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:57)        ... 2 more
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2,141ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Any thoughts or insight to fix please let me know

I updated the gradle properties and this pops up now. I am new to flutter and I getting the packages from GitHub and try to make the app work

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your `build.gradle` content?

The error states that you have: `Illegal character in path at index 62`

Comment: Hi yes this shows distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace your `gradle-wrapper.properties` with the config below?

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Comment: I was able to replace the gradle -wrapper properties thank you